# Web API throws error on live but runs fine in local

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, build, asp.net-web-api, azure-web-roles

I am developing an web API along with webrole in a MVC-Azure app. Everything was fine before. But one of our users reported some of the API methods are returning a 500. where others does not. But it's working fine on my local.
When I checked in log, I found:

```
Could not load type 'myWebAPI.WebApiApplication'. at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ReportTopLevelCompilationException() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) 

Could not load type 'myWebAPI.WebApiApplication'. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseFile(String physicalPath, VirtualPath virtualPath) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.Parse() at System.Web.Compilation.BaseTemplateBuildProvider.get_CodeCompilerType() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvider.GetCompilerTypeFromBuildProvider(BuildProvider buildProvider) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.ProcessBuildProviders() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at System.Web.Compilation.ApplicationBuildProvider.GetGlobalAsaxBuildResult(Boolean isPrecompiledApp) at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileGlobalAsax() at System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.EnsureTopLevelFilesCompiled() 

Could not load type 'myWebAPI.WebApiApplication'. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessException(Exception ex) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseStringInternal(String text, Encoding fileEncoding) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ParseString(String text, VirtualPath virtualPath, Encoding fileEncoding) 

Could not load type 'myWebAPI.WebApiApplication'. at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.GetType(String typeName, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnError) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.ProcessInheritsAttribute(String baseTypeName, String codeFileBaseTypeName, String src, Assembly assembly) at System.Web.UI.TemplateParser.PostProcessMainDirectiveAttributes(IDictionary parseData)
```

NOTE: The webAPI app is dependent on the webrole app.

Comment: Have you tried to republish the solution?

Comment: `The webAPI app is dependent on the webrole app.` - In what way. Can you show us some code please?

Comment: @AndreiMikhalevich I havn't, but I will. Actually, I was concentrating on why.

Comment: @ramiramilu The webrole project is acting like the data layer and service layer to the API.